# how to set dynamic height for a relative positioned div which contains multiple absolute div

Tags: javascript, css-position

I have to set auto height for relative positioned div which contains multiple absolute position div's inside it. Without mentioning height to the outer div positioned relative the content inside the absolute div is not visible due to overflow:hidden property.

Is there any Javascript to make this possible.. If so please advise me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternatively you could remove the `overflow:hidden` and the content will be visible.

Comment: Why you have `absolute` children on your div?

Comment: @elclanrs `clearfix` doesn't work for `absolute` elements. It works for `float` elements.

Comment: @Bazz if i remove overflow:hidden the rest of the page is getting disturbed.. because width has also not been set and there is a left navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Since absolute positioned children does not affect parents size, you should calculate the bounds of parent div manually. For instance to get height of the parent you should iterate over child elements and find maximum value of child's top plus height, and to get width you should find maximum left plus width pair. You can use the following function to adjust parent's width an height:

```
function setSize() {
  var i, count,
      maxWidth = 0,
      maxHeight = 0,
      top, left, width, height,
      parent = document.getElementById('parent');

  for(i=0,count=parent.childNodes.length;i<count;i++) {
    if(parent.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1) {
      top = parent.childNodes[i].offsetTop;
      left = parent.childNodes[i].offsetLeft;
      width = parent.childNodes[i].offsetWidth;
      height = parent.childNodes[i].offsetHeight;
      if(top + height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = top + height;
      }
      if(left + width > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = left + width;
      }
    }
  }
  parent.style.width = maxWidth + 'px';
  parent.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
}
```

the function assumes that you parent div have an `id="parent"`

Working example you can find here: http://jsbin.com/ifelur/1/edit